# 「プログラムがエラーなく実行できた」時の表現

Tags: python

「**プログラム（記述したコード）が、エラーが起こることなく実行できた時の表現**」にはどのようなものがありますか？
また、なんと表現するのが一般的なのでしょうか。

私が聞いたことがあるのは、

- 通る
- 走る

などです。

私は「通った」と表現してしまいますが、これが適切であるのか、他者に伝わるのか心配です。

Comment: 興味深い質問ではありますが、このサイトの対象トピックからは外れているのでは？ 正解のない主観的な質問になっていそうです。これらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。ヘルプを参考にし、以後注意したいと思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

難しく考えず、シンプルに **正常終了**、**異常終了** と表現するのが一般的だと思います。

[正常終了 | 用語検索 - ZDNet Japan](https://japan.zdnet.com/glossary/exp/%E6%AD%A3%E5%B8%B8%E7%B5%82%E4%BA%86/)

> 正常終了とは、実行したプログラムやジョブ、またはシステムの終了時に、障害が発生することなく、意図したとおりに終了することである。
> 正常終了に対して、不具合の発生などを原因として通常どおりに終了できないことは、異常終了と呼ばれる。

---

#### 余談

質問中で例として挙げられている「通る」は『テストを通る (=パスする)』、「走る」はエラー等を考慮せず単にプログラムが『実行される』だと思うので、想定している場面で使うのは不適当です。

Comment: 質問のニュアンスから [APIはなぜ「叩く」のですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60000/26370) のように俗語・通称のような用語を求めているのかと思いましたが、確かにこの回答の方が単純に正論ですね。